# Are there any diagrammers implemented in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, diagramming

I need to develop a javascript based diagrammer for designing node-and-connector diagrams for things like process flow, activity diagram etc. I am planning to use jQuery's drag-and-drop and templates to do this. But, is there any similar solution already out there that I could reuse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [JointJS](http://www.jointjs.com/index.html#about). It uses [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com) for rendering the diagrams, so it's pretty smooth. It already has the most common diagram types built in (UML, Flowchart, ERD, Petri net, ...) and can easily be extended.